# AddForce in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

i want the player to stop immediatly from moving when i release the arrow buttons , but it keep sliding a little bit because of the effece of the rigidBody2D.addForce . 
here is my code :

```
void Update () {
    forceX = 0f;

    var absVelX = Mathf.Abs (GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity.x);
    var absVelY = Mathf.Abs (GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity.y);
    if (controller.moving.x != 0) {

        if (absVelX < maxVelocity.x) {
            forceX = speed * controller.moving.x;
            transform.localScale = new Vector3 (forceX > 0 ? 1 : -1, 1, 1);
            animator.SetInteger ("Controller", 1);

        }else if (controller.moving.x == 0) {
        }


    } else {
        animator.SetInteger ("Controller", 0);
    }

    GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().AddForce(new Vector2 (forceX, 0));

}
```

thank you in advance .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you add a force to a Rigidbody, the physics engine increases its velocity. In every physics update, the physics engine modifies this velocity based on collisions, friction, etc and then it computes the new position based on the new velocity. If you want the rigidbody to stop moving immediately, you have to set the velocity to zero:

```
GetComponent<Rigidbody2d>().velocity = Vector2.zero;
```

Comment: it Works thank you very much , i need to concentrate on logic in the next time .